# Daemon thinks it's connected but keeps saying "there were 0 blocks in the last 90 minutes..."

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon, synchronization, aeon

Alright, so I had been using the monero gui wallet for a couple weeks by running my own local node and everything was fine. Then one time when I opened the wallet for some reason it wouldn't connect to Daemon. So after trying to find a solution, I decided to just resync the blockchain by deleting the file ~/.bitmonero/lmdb/data.mdb. However when I started the wallet again Daemon seems to think that it is synced at a block height of 1/1 and it keeps saying "there were 0 blocks in the last 90 minutes, there might be large hash rate changes, or we might be partitioned, cut off from the monero network or under attack. Or it could just be sheer bad luck."
I'm really not sure what to do to get it to work again. I've already tried to completely delete the wallet from my computer and redownload it but that didn't work either. Oh, I also use the Aeon wallet and it seems that this problem is also occurring on that wallet so this might be an issue with daemon and not the wallets but I'm still clueless about how to fix it.

Comment: 5 seconds after posting this question I found out it was an issue with my VPN...Hopefully my stupidity helps someone...

Comment: When you say "Daemon thinks it's connected", what makes you think it thinks so ?

Comment: @Dan - Which version of the software are you using? If the daemon, for both aeon and Monero, gets stuck on 1/1, there might be a network issue by the way.